# Prevent to add suffix for some URL when using JRoute

Tags: joomla-3.x

When calling JRoute, if the user has enabled in Joomla! to add suffix to url, is-there a way to don't add suffix to some urls ?

In some cases using url with suffix for doing ajax request doesn't work, so for this kind of case i need to remove suffix to url.

Do-you have an idea to do it ?

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 1):

Actually you shouldn't use JRoute for ajax functions as said in [joomla docs](https://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component), so just use the system url like: *index.php?option=com_component&task=mycontroller.function* without JRoute function.

> In general, you should only apply this to URLs that users and/or search engines are able to see. For example, there is no need to transform URLs used in redirects that immediately result in other redirects.

Hope this helps